# Неправильный MarkDown в справке

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

На [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) странице справки есть такой фрагмент:

> ###Репутация повышается в следующих случаях:
>
> - ...
> - ...

и

> ###Репутация понижается в следующих случаях:
>
> - ...
> - ...

Наверное имелись в виду заголовки, но сейчас они выгледят как решётки.

Comment: Пробела не хватает, вроде.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, похоже на то.